# Excluding an exact phrase from a Lucene query

Tags: lucene

I am trying to write a Lucene query to return documents that contain a specific word ("System"), but only when that word falls outside of a specific phrase ("System issue").  I need to accomplish this without excluding documents that contain the longer phrase altogether, since many of my documents contain the word "System" both as part of the phrase I wish to ignore ("System issue") and elsewhere.

Using the below data as an example, I want to return document 2, which contains the word "System" outside of the phrase "System issue", but not document 1, which contains the word "System" only within the phrase "System issue":

Document 1:

> "System issue - foobar"

Document 2:

> "System issue - System is down"

Comment: The easiest (but probably not the most convenient or the fastest) way is to run two queries and remove the result of one from the other.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the steps to do it this way?  I am failing to understand how I can get the desired set without running into the same problem.  For instance, in my example data, how can I return document 2 without returning document 1?

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't read the question carefully enough.